# Does IdentityServer4 have API to validate an access token?

Tags: c#, php, .net, identityserver4

I have an Identity Server which is built by using IdentityServer4.

I have 2 applications (1 .NET, 1 PHP) accessing resource each other and using this Identity Server to validate access token in request header.

In Identity Server application I add a client config as below

```
clients.Add(
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "myClientId",
                ClientName = "My Client Name",
                ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    "php.es.api"
                }
            });
```

From .NET application I can get access token easily by calling method RequestClientCredentialsAsync with scope "php.es.api". Then add this bearer token and send request to PHP API.

The problem is I don't know whether IdentityServer4 has API so that PHP application can call it to authenticate the access token. I google and don't find any document mentions about this API.

Do I have to write new API in Identity Server application for PHP or other applications not .NET to validate token?

.NET application access resource from PHP application as below.

[image: IdentityServer4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard endpoint for this called the [introspection endpoint](https://leastprivilege.com/2015/11/25/reference-tokens-and-introspection/) and it is supported by IdentityServer4. Your best bet is to find an oauth client in PHP that does this. If you are using self-contained bearer tokens you can validate tokens without the need for back-channel communication because the bearer tokens are signed by your provider and your provider has its keys listed in the discovery document required to validate the tokens (/.well-known/openid-configuration). I am not too familiar with PHP to point you in the right direction as to what cool libraries there might be out there

Comment: I try to call introspect endpoint, but it always returns the login page, it's not the object as in the document of IdentityServer4, although my granttype is ClientCredentials.

Comment: I haven't found a library to validate access token in PHP. I am temporarily using introspection endpoint, and if I add secret in scope, it works well. Thanks a lot.